# How do the training and cross validation mean squared error curves behave as a function of $\lambda$?

Tags: regularization, ridge-regression, mse

I am currently looking into methods of choosing optimal tuning parameter $\lambda$ for ridge regression. I think that for the cross-validation the MSE should be relatively high for $\lambda=0$. Then I expect that regularization, i.e. $\lambda>0$ would result in a sharp drop in the cross- validation error, improving the fit of the model. I believe that for positive - yet, small $\lambda$ the MSE should be minimized? Then as the $\lambda$ increases, the MSE should also increase? Does the training MSE work in a similar fashion?

Comment: training mse is minimised at lambda=0, since then you are not trading off coefficient size vs training error